# Reliable way to test if navigator properties are overwritten with a getter function

Tags: javascript

With a script it's possible to overwrite the navigator.plugins property in Chrome and Firefox with

```
Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'plugins', {
    get: function() {
        return [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    },
});
```

So basically the property is read-only but with the getter function it's possible to overwrite. (Not in the console but in a script tough) So how could I test if the property has been overwritten?

I read about receiving the toString property of the function which should return [native code]

```
function isNative(fn) {
    return (/\{\s*\[native code\]\s*\}/).test('' + fn);
}
```

Now my question: How can I test if the getter was overwritten with the `get:function()`.. above?

Comment: may be better to address your original problem which may be solved without going down this route

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few techniques that can get you *closer* to determining whether the function was overwritten:

- In Chrome, at least, `plugins` exists on `Navigator.prototype`, not on `window.navigator`. If the code is running in Chrome and the property is directly on `navigator`, it has been overwritten.

```
const definitelyPatched = navigator.hasOwnProperty('plugins');
```

- If the property has been put on the prototype, check that the property descriptor matches the default: it should be enumerable and configurable. If it's not, it's been overwritten.

```
const descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Navigator.prototype, 'plugins');
const definitelyPatched = descriptor.set || !descriptor.enumerable || descriptor.configurable;
```

- In combination with the above, a nearly foolproof method would be to bypass the patched function's custom `toString` by using `Function.prototype.toString` and `.call`:

```js
const fn = function() {
  return [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
};
fn.toString = function() {
  return '[native code]';
};

Object.defineProperty(Navigator.prototype, 'plugins',
  {
      get: fn,
});

const descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Navigator.prototype, 'plugins');
console.log(Function.prototype.toString.call(descriptor.get));
```

This would only fail if `Function.prototype.toString` has been overwritten too, and such patching can be detected [in multi-realm environments](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-function-implementation-hiding).

Comment: Thanks so much also for the links!